# Python/selenium - locate elements 'By' - specify locator strategy with variable?

Tags: python, selenium

Having created a selenium browser and retrieved a web page, this works fine:

```
...
if selenium_browser.find_element(By.ID, 'id_name'):
    print "found"
...
```

given a tuple like this:

```
tup = ('ID', 'id_name')
```

I'd like to be able to locate elements like this:

```
if selenium_browser.find_element(By.tup[0], tup[1]):
```

but I get this error

```
AttributeError: type object 'By' has no attribute 'tup'
```

How can I do this without having to write:

```
if tup[0] == 'ID':
    selenium_browser.find_element(By.ID, tup[1])
    ...
elif tup[0] == 'CLASS_NAME':
    selenium_browser.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, tup[1])
    ...
elif tup[0] == 'LINK_TEXT':
    etc etc
```

http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html?highlight=#module-selenium.webdriver.common.by

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to directly provide a tuple to `find_element`, add a `*` in front:

```
locator = (By.ID, 'id')
element = driver.find_element(*locator)
```

Or with the method provided as a string:

```
locator = ('ID', 'id_name')
driver.find_element(getattr(By, locator[0]), locator[1])
```

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is off.

The docs say this should be used like such: `find_element(by='id', value=None)`

So instead of

```
if selenium_browser.find_element(By.tup[0], tup[1]):
```

You should do

```
if selenium_browser.find_element(tup[0], tup[1]):
#or
if selenium_browser.find_element(by=tup[0], value=tup[1]):
```

You may or may not need to lowercase the `by` element IE `tup[0].lower()`